# prevent further triggers of delete cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

In my Create/Update cloud functions i can prevent further triggers from one cloud function to another by adding a field value "preventFurtherTriggers"

```
exports.onUpdateAll = functions.firestore
  .document("content/{authorId}")
  .onUpdate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    const data = snapshot.data();

    const newEventData = Object.assign(data, {
      preventFurtherTriggers: true,
    });
   admin.firestore().collection("all").doc(authorId).collection("events").doc(eventId).update(newEventData);
});
```

```
exports.onUpdateEvent = functions.firestore
  .document("all/{authorId}/events/{eventId}")
  .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    const newValue = change.after.data();

    if (newValue.preventFurtherTriggers === true) return;
    console.log("recursive function stopped!");
    }
});
```

Below i have three cloud functions which are triggered by the client.

1: One cloud function removes all the events in a particular group for all users.

3: Second cloud function would be to delete events for only one user.

2: Third cloud functions removes group and all the events in that group for all users.

The problem arrises when the function "onDeleteEventsForOneUser" or "onDeleteEventsForOneUser" deletes events and therefore triggers the function "onDeleteEvent".

How can i stop "onDeleteEventForAllUsers". being triggered. With a update/create i can pass data in the body and therefore prevent further triggers. Can something similar be achieved with the delete cloud function? pass body or data that i later can compare against? And stop a delete cloud function from executing?

```
exports.onDeleteEventForAllUsers = functions.firestore
  .document("all/{authorId}/userevents/{eventId}")
  .onDelete(async (snapshot, context) => {
    const data = snapshot.data();

    const eventid = context.params.eventId;
    const eventingroup = data.eventingroup;

    const allContentFollowersRef = admin
      .firestore()
      .collectionGroup("userevents")
      .where("eventingroup", "==", eventingroup)
      .where("eventid", "==", eventid);
    const querySnapshot = await allContentFollowersRef.get();

    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      doc.ref.delete(data);
    });
  });
```

```
exports.onDeleteEventsForOneUser = functions.firestore
  .document("following/{groupId}/followinggroup/{userId}")
  .onDelete(async (snapshot, context) => {
    const groupId = context.params.groupId;
    const userId = context.params.userId;

    const contentInMapRef = admin
      .firestore()
      .collectionGroup("userevents")
      .where("eventingroup", "==", groupId);

    const userContentPathRef = admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("all")
      .doc(userId)
      .collection("userevents");

    const contentQuerySnapshot = await contentInMapRef.get();
    contentQuerySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        userContentPathRef.doc(doc.id).delete();
      }
    });
  });
```

```
exports.onDeleteGroupAndEvents = functions.firestore
  .document("group/{groupId}")
  .onDelete(async (snapshot, context) => {
    const groupId = context.params.groupId;

    const groupsRef = admin
      .firestore()
      .collectionGroup("userevents")
      .where("eventingroup", "==", groupId);
    const querySnapshot = await groupsRef.get();
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        doc.ref.delete();
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: What's the problem? Deletes can't repeat. Once the document is gone, it can't be deleted again to trigger another invocation of the function for the same document. If there is a specific case you're observing, you'll need to edit the question to explain that in more detail.  Since we can't see the code in your delete function, it's hard to imagine why it would trigger another delete.

Comment: Hey Doug, I have now updated my question. Hope it is more clear now. I have multiple cloud functions which delete data (Group, an event for all users, an event for one user) The problem arrises when one cloud function triggers a second one. Is it possible to stop this behaviour somehow? Like i mentioned earlier. I manage this in Create and Update with an added field called "preventFurtherTriggers". The reason that the structure is build this way is because all users have a duplicate of same data.

Comment: You can't really choose to "pass" anything to a Firestore trigger.  It just executes based on what happens to the document, and you get the contents of the document in the trigger.

Comment: With create/update i can however include a field value within the cloud function before it is being passed to the next cloud function. Can you pass a body with a delete function or is there anyway to differentiate where the triggers have been passed from? Thank you for responding!

Comment: You can't "pass" anything. The function just receives the content of the document that was deleted.